# Mouse Hover event not firing over a panel in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, mousehover

i am trying to write a code on Mouse_Hover event of a panel in my winform app using c#. This is my code ..

```
private void viewscreen_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        statuspnl.Enabled = true;
        statuspnl.Visible = true;
    }
```

but the problem is the event is not firing when i am taking the mouse over the viewscreen panel

```
 // viewscreen
        // 
        this.viewscreen.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
        this.viewscreen.Controls.Add(this.statuspnl);
        this.viewscreen.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(208, 16);
        this.viewscreen.Name = "viewscreen";
        this.viewscreen.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(370, 290);
        this.viewscreen.TabIndex = 0;
        this.viewscreen.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.viewscreen_MouseHover);
```

Comment: How are you attaching this event handler?

Comment: I mean how does your code know that viewscreen_MouseHover handles the MouseHover event for your viewscreen control?

Comment: How does your code know that this event handler is for that particular event for that particular control? Automatically generated designer code? Explicitly setting the event handler on form load? What is the outcome of breakpoints/debugging? Have a look at your thread Arindam - you'll notice not a lot of people are helping you for a reason.

Comment: @DeeMac The answer to your question is already in the code posted.  Look at the last line of code in the question.  He attached the handler explicitly to the viewscreen_MouseHover method inside the same class that holds the viewScreen control.  Notice the "this" before both the control and the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please create one window app with the name as "panelvisible". Add one form as "Form1"
and add these code in respective files.

Code for designer

```
namespace panelvisible
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 36);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.panel1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.panel1_MouseHover);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(49, 42);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(31, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Hello";
            this.label1.Visible = false;
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 70);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(118, 10);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.panel2.Visible = false;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(494, 205);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
    }
}
```

Code for code behind

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace panelvisible
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label1.Visible = true;
            this.label1.Enabled = true;
            this.panel2.Visible = true;
            this.panel2.Enabled = true;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: thanks .. i am unable to vote for ur ans .. bcoz that guy ate my rep

Comment: this doesn't work when I mouse hover on the squares that I draw during the onpaint method :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you have this code?

```
this.viewscreen.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.viewscreen_MouseHover);
```

It should be added automatically but make sure you don't change this...
Another way - remove mouse hover event and add it again.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Is you view screen a form or is it realy a panel?
And is you panel / form enabled?