# Changing Mouse Cursor to pencil in Drawing panel

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

In my Winform app, i have a Drawing panel.

when i move my cursor within the drawing panel, cursor should be changed to *pencil*
how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Cursor called 'Pencil' within Cursor Class,See the complete cursor listing here :

[Complete Cursor Listing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors_properties.aspx)

However You can try **Custom Cursors**

Visual Studio allows you to create cursor (.cur) files. A cursor file is a bitmap file with .cur extension. To create a cursor file, right click on your project and select Add New Item menu item. After that, select Cursor File from the items. This action will add a default Cursor1.cur file

[image]

Once a cursor file is added, you will land in bitmap editor where you can change the bitmap using drawing tools as you can see

[image]

Now copy Cursor1.cur file to your Debug or Release folder where your executable file is stored.

Once a file is saved, we can create a cursor from the cursor file using following code snippet.

**C# Code:**

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(Application.StartupPath +  "\\Cursor1.cur");
```

**VB.NET Code:**

```
Me.Cursor = New Cursor(Application.StartupPath + "\Cursor1.cur")
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the Control's Cursor Property to a pencil cursor.  It appears that it is not one of the options in the designer or one of the values in Cursors, so you would have to go about it this way:

```
Cursor pencil = new Cursor("Path to cursor Icon file");
Control.Cursor = pencil;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at these examples.

For custom cursors

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors

For Panel Hover

[Mouse Hover event not firing over a panel in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403375/mouse-hover-event-not-firing-over-a-panel-in-c-sharp)